# Custom gradle plugin - buildscript dependencies

Tags: gradle-plugin

I am trying to write a custom gradle plugin (kotlin/kotlin dsl) that will allow me to set all sorts of things in the build scripts.
I would like to add dependencies on build tooling, such as detekt, log4j2, ktlint, and even configure them.  So for example, including the plugin will add detekt tasks to the build.

I have a basic binary plugin with a task, but I am having difficulty constructing a good web-search to find what I need.  Can anyone please:

- provide some clues
- give me some search terms
- point me at an article
- or point me at a good example?

Thanks in advance.

Phill

Edit: this plugin class compiles, and seems acceptible to the receiving build script, but no detekT tasks appear in the receiving build.

```
class BuildCommonPlugin: Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.dependencies
           .create("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:1.19.0")
    }
}
```

EDIT: At the comment I am using a 'buildSrc' type plugin.  The irritating thing is that I need to duplicate this in each grade project, and when I find an improvement I need to update them all.

How easy is it to convert a 'buildSrc' into a publishable plugin?

Comment: You may be better served with a buildSrc: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources

Comment: Thanks xeruf: That is what I have resorted to for now.  At least I can copy the buildSrc directory between projects as a self-contained entity.  A plugin hosted on an artefactory would be much better though.